# GroupJoin: exception thrown: System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to write a query to get all restaurant tables if exists or not a opened sale on it.
if a sale exists on a table I want to get the sum and couple details.that is my code:

```
   db.SALETABLES
  .GroupJoin(
        db.SALES.Where(c => c.CLOSEDTIME == null),
        t => t.ID,
        sa => sa.ID_TABLE,
     (ta, s) => new
            {
               ta.ID,
               ta.DESCRIPTION,
                NR_SALE = s.Any() ? s.First().NR_SALE : 0,
                IDSALE = s.Any() ? s.First().ID : 0,
                IDUSER = s.Any() ? s.First().IDUSER : 0,
                USERNAME = s.Any() ? s.First().USERS.USERNAME :"" ,
                SALESUM = s.Any() ? s.First().SALES_DETAIL.Sum(p => p.PRICE * p.CANT) : 0
                         }
```

but got this error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll

thanks for any help

Comment: Please post the classes used in the query, so we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify the exception, but I assume it's about client-side evaluation (CSE), and you configured EF to throw an exception when it occurs.

It may be `First()` that triggers CSE, or `GroupJoin`. The former can easily be fixed by using `FirstOrDefault()`. The `GroupJoin` has more to it.

In many cases it isn't necessary to use `GroupJoin` at all, of `Join`, for that matter. Usually, manually coded joins can and should be replaced by navigation properties. That doesn't only make the code better readable, but also avoids a couple of issues EF 2.x has with `GroupJoin`.

Your `SaleTable` class (I'm not gonna follow your database-driven names) should have a property `Sales`:

```
public ICollection<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
```

And if you like, `Sale` could have the inverse navigation property:

```
public SaleTable SaleTable { get; set; }
```

Configured as

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SaleTable>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Sales)
    .WithOne(e => e.SaleTable)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.SaleTableId) // map this to ID_TABLE
    .IsRequired();
```

Now using a table's `Sales` property will have the same effect as `GroupJoin` —a unique key, here a `SaleTable`, with an owned collection— but without the issues.

The next improvement is to simplify the query. In two ways. 1. You repeatedly access the first `Sale`, so use the `let` statement. 2. The query is translated into SQL, so don't worry about null *references*, but do prepare for null *values*. The improved query will clarify what I mean.

```
var query = from st in db.SaleTables
            let firstSale = st.Sales.FirstOrDefault()
            select new
            {
                st.ID,
                NrSale = (int?)firstSale.NrSale ?? 0,
                IdSale = (int?)firstSale.ID ?? 0,
                ...
                SalesSum = (int?)firstSale.SalesDetails.Sum(p => p.Price * p.Cant) ?? 0
            }
```

Using `NrSale = firstSale.NrSale,` would throw an exception for `SaleTable`s without `Sales` (Nullable object must have a value).

Comment: Wow, we posted almost simultaneously (you were the first though :-) I'm curious if you tried the suggested query - I had to play with several variant before getting to my answer.

Comment: @Ivan Hehe, funny :) I did try this using a similar case from my own little portfolio so I'm pretty confident it'll do. Your analysis is more profound, I wasn't aware of this inevitable exception when using `First`. Although when using it, EF switched to CSE and then failed with "Sequence contains no elements".

Comment: I've just tried it with my little test project. Of course it eliminated the OP exception (I had no doubt about that). Unfortunately show a lot of client eval warnings regarding the `Sum` expression and also generates separate subquery for each projected `firstSale` property. Even more weird, if replace the `let` part of your query with the equivalent `from firstSale in st.SALES.Where(s => s.CLOSEDTIME == null).Take(1)`, it gets even worse. So contrary to the usual better translation with using navigation properties, such type of queries work better with manual joins. Bad EF Core, waiting v3 :)

Comment: OMG, I guess I have to replicate this exactly 1:1. My case only warns me about unpredictable results when using `FirstOrDefault()` without ordering but happily proceeds translating into SQL with a SUM statement. That's the problem with EF core, minor differences may blow up the whole thing. I'll leave my answer here because I think the approach in general may help OP and future readers. Thanks!

Comment: This makes me wonder... I used Linqpad, so it's EF core in "classic" .Net Framework. Maybe it's different with .Net core? Something for me to find out...

Comment: I don't think so. I'm also testing EF Core with "classic" .Net Framework console app (no time to get to .Net Core yet, and my primary job application is still on full framework and due to its size probably will stay long on it, you know). What about LINQPad, never used it, so have no idea what it does/uses. Anyway, of course the answer should stay, I just wanted to exchange some info with you (it's always been a pleasure to read your comments/answers). Take care.

Answer (score 3):

Since the exception is by the EF Core infrastructure, apparently you are hitting current EF Core implementation bug.

But you can help EF Core query translator (thus avoiding their bugs caused by missing use cases) by following some rules when writing your LINQ to Entities queries. These rules will also eliminate in most of the cases the client evaluation of the query (or exception in EF Core 3.0+).

One of the rules which is the origin of issues with this specific query is - *never* use `First`. The LINQ to Objects behavior of `First` is to throw exception if the set is empty. This is not natural for SQL which naturally supports and returns `NULL` even for values which normally do not allow `NULL`. In order to emulate the LINQ to Objects behavior, EF Core has to evaluate `First()` client side, which is not good even if it works. Instead, use `FirstOrDefault()` which has the same semantics as SQL, hence is translated.

To recap, use `FirstOrDefault()` when you need the result to be a single "object" or `null`, or `Take(1)` when you want the result to be a set with 0 or one elements.

In this particular case, it's better to incorporate the 0 or 1 related `SALE` rule directly into the join subquery, by removing the `GroupJoin` and replacing it with `SelectMany` with correlated `Where`. And the `Any()` checks are replaced with `!= null` checks.

With that said, the modified working and fully server translated query looks like this:

```
var query = db.SALETABLES
    .SelectMany(ta => db.SALES
        .Where(s => ta.ID == s.ID_TABLE && s.CLOSEDTIME == null).Take(1), // <--
    (ta, s) => new
    {
        ta.ID,
        ta.DESCRIPTION,
        NR_SALE = s != null ? s.NR_SALE : 0,
        IDSALE = s != null ? s.ID : 0,
        IDUSER = s != null  ? s.IDUSER : 0,
        USERNAME = s != null ? s.USERS.USERNAME : "",
        SALESUM = s != null ? s.SALES_DETAIL.Sum(p => p.PRICE * p.CANT) : 0
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but .Take(1)  will return only one sale for all tables,not only for each (if exists)

Comment: @mrapi Darn, you are right of course! Then the `Take(1)` should go to the place of `DefaultIfEmpty()`, but then we are back to client evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, now it should be ok - turned into `CROSS APPLY` query which should take every first related record.

Comment: in this case the query is very slow and not returns all the tables.your first version (using GroupJoin) seems to work if i remove .Take(1) (there could be max 1 opened sale per table) . thanks